# How to expose methods of a private class?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a library. Let's call it `myLib`.

```
public class MyLib {
    public SomeClass someClass =  SomeClass.INSTANCE();

    private static MyLib _instance = null;
    
    public static MyLib INSTANCE()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new MyLib();

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

`SomeClass` looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    
    private static SomeClass _instance = null;
    
    public static SomeClass INSTANCE()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new SomeClass();

        return _instance;
    }
    
    public void print(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I'd like users to be able to write: `MyLib.INSTANCE().someClass.print("Hello World!");`

However, in its current form, `print` is inaccessible. I do not want the user to be able to simply bypass `MyLib.INSTANCE()` and write `SomeClass.INSTANCE().print("Hello World");` because some initialisation is done.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want that, then reduce the access level of `SomeClass.INSTANCE()` (eg to package private).

Comment: Is this your real code, especially with respect to the access modifiers?

Comment: If you classes are not in the same package you need make them public in order to be accessible. As per example SomeClass is not using default access modifier.

Comment: @Joni just example code but exactly represents what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @TraychoIvanov All classes are in the same package.

Comment: You need to make the use case more concrete. Frequently, for example, the nested class will implement some interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep `SomeClass` as an inner private class to prevent its direct accessibility and usage in `MyLib` class.

```
public static class MyLib {
    public SomeClass someClass =  SomeClass.INSTANCE();

    private static MyLib _instance = null;
    
    public static MyLib INSTANCE()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new MyLib();

        return _instance;
    }
    
    private static class SomeClass {
        
        private static SomeClass _instance = null;
        
        public static SomeClass INSTANCE()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new SomeClass();

            return _instance;
        }
        
        public void print(String message){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The solution to do without nested class using `protected` modifier

`MyLib` class in com.lib package

```
package com.lib;
public class MyLib {
    public SomeClass someClass =  SomeClass.INSTANCE();

    private static MyLib _instance = null;
    
    public static MyLib INSTANCE()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new MyLib();

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

`SomeClass` class in com.lib package

```
package com.lib;
public class SomeClass {
        
     private static SomeClass _instance = null;
        
        protected static SomeClass INSTANCE()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new SomeClass();

            return _instance;
        }
        
        public void print(String message){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
```

Accessing it in your main project (i.e. different package)

```
package com.project;
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyLib.INSTANCE().someClass.print("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: but this requires `SomeClass` to be a nested class of  `MyLib`. Any way for this not to be the case? I have a few of these `SomeClass` and I do not want to put every one of them into essntially 1 class.

Comment: @pookie Yes, we can do that. Just appended the above answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To make `SomeClass.print` accessible, `SomeClass` itself needs to be accessible.

To make `SomeClass.INSTANCE` not accessible, remove the `public` modifier. Since you are only accessing from the same package, use the "default" access which has no explicit access modifier:

```
// public access
public class SomeClass {
    // package-only access
    static SomeClass INSTANCE() { }
    // public access
    public void print(String message) { }
}
```